# RangeError: Maximum call stack size in production only

Tags: javascript, angular, heroku, production, angular10

In my Angular 10 app I'm getting following warning in production which I cannot reproduce locally:

```
main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:1 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at c.unsubscribe (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:1)
    at c._unsubscribeAndRecycle (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:1)
    at c.error (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:5)
    at u._trySubscribe (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:5)
    at u._trySubscribe (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:130)
    at u.subscribe (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:5)
    at t._subscribe (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:5)
    at t.subscribe (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:5)
    at c.notifyNext (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:5)
    at r._next (main-es2015.f525fab5b0fb3ab34ccf.js:1)
```

The problem occurs after navigating to one of the routes, so I guess it's related to lazy loading.
I know that this would indicate that I have infinite loops or circular dependency, but the problem is that it works just fine locally. And what I mean by that is running the app in dev **or** compiling in prod mode and running compiled files using express server (just like I do it in production) do not throw any errors or warnings.

I use node v. 12.16.1 and npm v. 6.13.4 both in prod and dev environment.
I would appreciate any tips on how to debug or recreate the error on my machine.

Comment: My question is: when this error occurs? While uploading the build to heroku instance or going to any specific routes? Circular dependency you can see in the dev console, and I suggest you try to remove them and then upload it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the error occurs when I go to one specific route. All the dev console shows is the error attached in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix it. The problem was caused by `retryWhen` RxJS operator. I didn't have my websocket service URI set on Heroku in config vars, so the operator got into infinite loop causing maximum call stack size error.